# Django - disable a system check for a specific management command

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have a circular problem with a system check in django:

```
$   python manage.py search_index --rebuild -f

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
{'search.documents.applications': 'entities'}: (search.E001) No elasticsearch index 'entities' exists
        HINT: Run `manage.py search_index --rebuild -f` to recreate then repopulate the indices.
```

One workaround is to [disable this check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909861/django-disable-one-of-system-checks) using system settings but I don't want to have to change system settings to disable it, deploy, run the rebuild, change back, redeploy every time I attach a different search index or flush elasticsearch.

Is there a way of disabling this error (eg by overriding that setting) by passing something to the actual manage.py command?

Comment: Why don't you do what is suggested by [the second answer to the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53568682/662345)? (The topmost 4-line snippet.)

Comment: Oh, yes, that's neat, I skim-read that and saw the system setting without realising I could then control that from the environment. Was hoping that there'd me a more general solution but that's a good one to have in the pocket, thanks @AntonisChristofides